# How can I add slide numbers to a powerpoint presentation using Open XML .net sdk?

Tags: c#, powerpoint, openxml

I am trying to add slide numbers to my presentation using C# and open XML. I have checked the documentation and have added the slide number shape to my presentation but when I open the presentation using PowerPoint the numbers wont appear in the textbox, it just says "Slide Number".

I would like the text box to be filled with the slide number and to dynamically update when I change the slides position in the PowerPoint presentation. How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found it. The key was to create a Field with the type slide number and append it to the paragraph.